# Control property/aggregation updates and re-rendering

Tags: sapui5

If I update a property or aggregation on a control how do I prevent it from rerendering?

For example, if I add a member to an aggregation, I want to render just the new member, not do a full rerender.

Looking for general advice...

Comment: interesting question, think you may need to share more information or code

Comment: Let's say you had a custom control that displayed images. Images are an aggregation of the control. As the user scrolls the page, more images are to be added to the aggregation, but totally reloading the control will give a bad user experience.
This is a case where only rendering the new items is needed.

Comment: I think you need to do list binding via a model, direct changes to an aggregation forces a rerender in many controls, for eg. take a look at http://jsbin.com/yahok/1/edit?html,console,output the table is rendered once only, it shows over 2000's entries retrieved via an OData service 100 records at a time, search on sdk for "growing" also for other techniques

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am adding items by updating the underlying model, so yes I'm using data binding.
But good idea for searching for "growing", I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it if its a custom control.

In Custom control, provide a new method that add's the delta part and renders it (you can use jQuery).

The new method should also add the aggregation, but should not trigger re-rendering.
Check the add aggregation method definition

**`addAggregation(sAggregationName, oObject, bSuppressInvalidate?)`**

the `bSuppressInvalidate` if true, the control doesn't re-render.

Example:

```
customControl.prototype.addNewImage(img){

// some code to manipulate dom and add image
//...
//...

this.addAggregation(sAggregationName, img, false)

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How would that work if the control's aggregation is data-bound? In this case, it makes no sense to add items to the aggregation manually, since they will be already added modifying the model. I would expect that UI5 takes care for rendering only the new items automatically. In my case, I want to implement endless scrolling. Currently, the whole control refreshes once I update the model.